# android ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership and ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, group-membership

I need to find out if a particular contact is a member of a given group.  I have been working with the code below and have proved that it works using a handset running Gingerbread.  However I have been trying to run it on my HTC One S running Android version 4.0.3 and it is failing.  Has the API spec changed?  My code is below.

```
public boolean checkGroupMembership(String groupID, String contactID, Context ctx) {
            ContentResolver groupContentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
                        String select = "contact_id=" + contactID + 
                    " AND " + GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " = " + groupID +
                    " AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership'";

            Cursor contactGroupCursor =  
                    groupContentResolver.query(
                        Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                        new String[] { GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID,  GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, GroupMembership.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP }, 
                        select,
                        null, 
                        null);
            int records = contactGroupCursor.getCount();
            try {
            while(contactGroupCursor.moveToNext()){
                String ContactID = contactGroupCursor.getString(contactGroupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID));
                String groupRowId = contactGroupCursor.getString(contactGroupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID));
                String InVisiblegroup = contactGroupCursor.getString(contactGroupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GroupMembership.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP));

                Log.d("DEBUG", "groupSourceId in checkGroupMembership: " + groupRowId + "  InVisiblegroup = " + InVisiblegroup);
                Log.d("DEBUG", "ContactID in checkGroupMembership: " + ContactID);          

                }       
            } 
            finally 
            {
                contactGroupCursor.close();
            }

            // see if the contact is in this group
            if (records > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {


            return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

In addition changing the query to purely find out what groups the contact is a member of:

```
String select = "contact_id=" + contactID;
```

results in the following debug output. In some cases groupRowID looks like a group ID, in others it is the contact number or the name of the contact.  Note that I am using my home landline to call test and this is appearing.  Also - I only have 10 groups defined on the handset and an id of 11, 12 and 13 is printed in the output... It could be that I'm missing something?  I definitely know that the contact_id I'm passing in is a member of the Coworkers group (group_ID 5 on my phone) but this is never returned in ICS.  I have independently verified the group membership for HOME using contact manager apps on both handsets.

> 11-04 11:48:21.980: D/DEBUG(10145): select in checkGroupMembership :
>   contact_id=133 11-04 11:48:21.990: D/DEBUG(10145): count of records in
>   checkGroupMembership: 13 11-04 11:48:22.000: D/DEBUG(10145):
>   groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: null  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04
>   11:48:22.000: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133
>   11-04 11:48:22.000: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in
>   checkGroupMembership:   InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.000:
>   D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04
>   11:48:22.000: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in checkGroupMembership:
>   004-414-83326995  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.000:
>   D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04
>   11:48:22.000: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in checkGroupMembership:
>   014-833-26995  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.000: D/MYOB(10145):
>   ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04 11:48:22.030:
>   D/MYOB(10145): groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: 01483326995 
>   InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in
>   checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145):
>   groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: 10  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04
>   11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133
>   11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in
>   checkGroupMembership: 11  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.030:
>   D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04
>   11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: 12 
>   InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in
>   checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145):
>   groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: 13  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04
>   11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133
>   11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in
>   checkGroupMembership: 7  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.030:
>   D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04
>   11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: 8 
>   InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in
>   checkGroupMembership: 133 11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145):
>   groupRowId in checkGroupMembership: 9  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04
>   11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133
>   11-04 11:48:22.030: D/DEBUG(10145): groupRowId in
>   checkGroupMembership: HOME  InVisiblegroup = 1 11-04 11:48:22.030:
>   D/DEBUG(10145): ContactID in checkGroupMembership: 133

P.S. please could someone with sufficient privileges please add "GroupMembership" as a tag to the site.

Comment: I have updated the code (runs in a separate application) that I've been using to list the groups on the device to also return groups.SYSTEM_ID and this is now bringing back group _IDs of 11, 12 and 13.  So now I'll have to figure out how to pick based on system_id which is a little tricky because some of the entries appear 2 or 3 times for the same group (based on Groups.TITLE). The code is:  final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/groups"),
    (new String[] { Groups._ID, Groups.SYSTEM_ID, Groups.TITLE}), null, null, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image below shows a dump of the groups from Gingerbread (Cyanogen) and ICS (HTC) produced using exactly the same code.  As you can see they are quite different in terms of how the data is presented.  For some reason the groups are duplicated to some extent in ICS.  So the question is how do I manage this across different versions if I'm planning to use the group _ID to perform lookups. Note that in the contacts app on ICS each group appears only once so how do I know which ID this refers to?

[image]

Comment: I guess the answer is to use the group name as the key data to perform lookups, which isn't what I'd call ideal, but it will work for both provided I de-dupe along the way.  If anyone is able to uncover why these are so different or how the differences can be addressed another way I'd be pleased to here from you.

Comment: I did figure this out ages ago, but haven't found time to update until now.  The query returns Phone Groups AND Google Groups and using the Group Name as the key works as it will pick up the correct membership regardless of where the user's contact entry is tagged - i.e. on the handset or in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's changed in group membership between Honeycomb and 4.0.3.

It would be easier to read all this if you used LogCat or even did a ListView and screenshot or something. It's hard to understand what your problem is. You can do a dump of 
ContactsContract.Groups to see what groups are defined for the database. Unless you're absolutely certain that both handsets have *exactly* the same data, you're gonna find differences. The only way to ensure they have exactly the same data is to wipe the contacts data off them and sync them both to a small test dataset.

Comment: Please see the image below which has a photo of what is returned as a dump of the groups - from Gingerbread and ICS.  As you can see it's very different...  <IMG src="https://c9790530-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/dannyruttle/gingerbread_ics.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7co_FyLC8GW4Hoa-NFNzr6--xyHzEEFyzsY9ZbwNKh_-PhPF8gn0dHQmv7kH-f9eQAW7gVDgqiq0TrA6eMwzkGgq8WYXiFafJwg_bHI2Fn_HOFfrCIM8fhsTPnGZ-LXG8d3hSUoKPZMkCo2zMqIClst3Fhtph4FE9Qm7jyKVzLo-A4Ai04p9ZUfr8ZtW2d2w7i3A0a-SL9Oi8VoaItTiKE2OS-IZ8Q%3D%3D&attredirects=0">